# Excel 2013: I have rows of records, each w/ a start and end date. How can I compile and summarize these in a separate table, month by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

My apologies; I can't yet post pictures so these are links to screencaps of my two worksheets:

[Projects](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/144658904/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-28%20at%205.55.44%20PM.png) / [Month by Month](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/144658904/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-28%20at%206.00.11%20PM.png)

As you may have guessed, I need to compile the data from the projects into a month by month summary, based on their respective start and end dates. I've looked into vlookup(), match() and offset()—it seems these functions may hold the key but it's a very complex task and I'm not really sure where to start. Is there a function (or set of functions) that's better suited for this kind of work? How would you tackle it?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at pivot tables. These are ideal for aggregating large data sets, slicing, dicing, filtering, etc.

Get started with pivot tables here: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Pivots/pivotstart.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link! I had fiddled with PivotTables a little and ended up with an illegible mess, but I'll try to learn them properly.